# A genre for soft electronic music

Tags: electronic-music

I am looking for an electronic music genre like house but with more melodies and more soft sounds, nothing aggressive and acid, more melodies and vocal and a little sad.

Is there a name for the genre I have described?

Comment: How about Trip Hop?

Comment: Thanks nice choise but most of song of these gener are full of percusion and "woody" sounds. almost no melodies.

Comment: You could perhaps try Balearic or Chillwave?

Comment: Darkwave? Ambient?

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words, in this case an audio sample :)

Comment: Tropical house might be a good option from the point of view of *good melodies*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two categories you might want to explore are "chillout" and "ambient dub".

However classifying music is an imprecise matter.

Comment: I agree is very imprecise. Chillout and ambient are good but somes songs are full of atmospheric and mysthic sounds and lack of melodies.

Comment: we are also living in a time of great 'fusion' so from that perspective almost any combination of ideas is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Chillout is ok, you could try also some kind of downtempo or deep house stuff.

For example, i can recommend you something like this:

normal link: www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA15Hk9v1T4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely what you're looking for, but I do have a few suggestions. Most low energy dance music is placed under the umbrella called "lounge" music. It's a very broad, unspecific term, but you can use that to help your search.

It's possible you might find something in R&B music. There's a plethora of popular songs from when it was popular back in the early 2000s.